# Get variables from post method on Python

Tags: javascript, python, rest, api

I made a python script that run some tasks, but i wanted it to launch when a client (frontend form) send a POST request to the server. So then I can get the variables from the client and run my script using that variable.

I think I will need to define a server on my python script that accept a post request, but I don't know where to start here. Can you help me a little bit with this?

Comment: you need to make an [Ajax call](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) to your python server to request information from javascript.

Comment: @KunalMukherjee ok thank you, but i need to send data from my client to python server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I have created a simple Flask server which appends person information into the list which is received from the client side.**

Here's the`app.py` which contains the flask Python server:

```
import os
import uuid

from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_cors import CORS

# instantiate the app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

# enable CORS
CORS(app)

#static list containing persons
persons = []

#test check route
@app.route('/status', methods=['GET'])
def status():
    return jsonify(dict({ 'message': 'Hello world'}))


@app.route('/person', methods=['POST'])
def add_person():
    post_data = request.get_json()
    response_object = dict({
            'id': uuid.uuid4().hex,
            'name': post_data.get('name'),
            'age': post_data.get('name')
        })
    persons.append(response_object)
    return jsonify(response_object), 201


@app.route('/person', methods=['GET'])
def get_persons():
    return jsonify(persons), 200

@app.route('/person/<person_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_person(person_id):
    person = list(filter(lambda x: x['id'] == person_id, persons))
    return jsonify(person), 200

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Save the script and run it using:**

`python app.py`

---

**This is a sample form that will post the name and age fields to your flask API:**

```js
// Write the following in index.js
window.onload = () => {


  document.querySelector('#btnSubmit').addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    const pName = document.querySelector('#pName').value;
    const pAge = document.querySelector('#pAge').value;

    if (!pName || !pAge) {
      alert('Please enter all fields to continue!');
      return;
    }

    const objectToSend = {
      name: pName,
      age: pAge
    };

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/person', {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify(objectToSend)
        headers: new Headers({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        })
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        return response.json()
      })
      .then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.err(err);
      });

  });

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>

<!-- <script src="index.js"> -->

<BODY>
  <FORM name="myform">
    <label>Name: <input id="pName" type="text" placeholder="Enter name"></label>

    <label>Age: <input type="number" id="pAge" placeholder="Enter age"></label>

    <input type="button" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit">

  </FORM>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

Hope that gives you a head start!

---

> Suggested Reading:
>
> [JS Fetch API](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch)

Comment: Awesome! thank you so much for your help now i know where to start

Comment: @JoangelDeLaRosa no problem :)